# Как можно обновлять только отдельный div на странице?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

У меня есть CRUD таблица, и после, к примеру, каждой ее правки я бы хотел обновлять только div, в котором находиться таблица, без обновления всей Index-страницы.

[image: Пример View] 
_Create.chtml

```
 <div class="modal-body">
    <h2>Create</h2>

    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
```

Contoller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Menu cust)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            sMenuRepository.Add(cust);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { fileID = cust.File_Id });               
        }
        return View(cust);

    }
```

Comment: у вас стоит тег `ajax`  наверное не зря...используйте его

Comment: я понимаю, что нужно использовать ajax. Как это использовать в контексте ASP.CORE? Могли бы привести пример? Спасибо!

Comment: на view через скрипт (jQuery `$.ajax();`)

Answer (score 0):

Справился:

**Conroller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ViewCreate()
{
    return PartialView("_Create");
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Menu cust)
{                   
  int create_file_id = cust.File_Id;
  sMenuRepository.Add(cust);           
  return RedirectToAction("ViewTable", create_file_id);
 }
```

**Parial View(_Create.chtml):**

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h2>Create</h2>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" data-ajax="true" data-ajax- 
    update="#divPartial" id="#order-form">
    ...
    ...
   <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button type="submit" id="approve-btn"
                        class="btn btn-success">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Main View:**

```
 <div id="divPartial">
            <partial name="_Table" model="Model" />                
        </div>
```